# Compare utility functions

Tags: utility, preferences

I recently joined an econ class. I am so lost on how to prove their equality. As a math standpoint, these are completely different equations. Please help!

```
u1 (x1, x2) = x1^(2/3) x2^(1/3)
u2 (x1, x2) = 4ln (x1) + 2 ln(x2) +3
```

Comment: Related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/2993/42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the logical positivist view of decision theory, utility functions are just descriptions of **observable behavior** and have no intrinsic meaning absent this vantage. In other words, $u(x) > u(y)$ indicates that $x$ would be chosen in favor of $y$, but the magnitude of the difference carries no addition information. If $u(x) = 1$ and $u(y) = 0$ the decision maker prefers $x$; if $u(x) = 10000$ and $u(y)= 0$ the decision maker prefers $x$. In either case, we can draw the same conclusions.

What does this mean with regard to your question? It tells us what we mean by *equality* of utility functions: we mean that these two different (so no definitionally equal) functions represent the same observable data. Specifically, exactly when $u_1(x) > u_1(y)$ do we also have $u_2(x) > u_2(y)$. As mentioned in the comments, this is precisely when we can compose $u_1$ with a strictly increasing function and pop out $u_2$. (This is because all we care about is the ordering between objects, and strictly increasing functions *preserve* order).

So, what might our strictly increasing function look like? Well, we can take the log, so that we get $\frac23 ln(x_1) + \frac13 ln(x_2)$ then multiplying by 6 and adding 3 does the trick. Each of these was strictly increasing so too is the composition:
$$ (x,y) \mapsto 6 (ln(x) + ln(y)) + 3$$
is our desired function.